# The order of axis when printing a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am working with 3d arrays in NumPy, and I have to look at the array elements a lot. Say I have array `a` where `a.shape` is `(10,5,3)`. I am using this is the sense of 3 planes of shape `(10,5)`, and I would like to view it as such.

For example if I

```
print(a)
```

I get

```
[[[ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [ 0 22  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [11 22  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [11  0  0]
  [11 22  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [ 0 22  0]
  [11  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [11 22  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [11 22 33]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [11 22  0]
  [ 0 22 33]
  [11 22  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0]]]
```

Whereas if I iterate through axis 2 and print like this, it is displayed like I want it:

```
>>> for i in range(a.shape[2]):
...     print(str(a[:,:,i]) + "\n")
...
[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 11  0  0]
 [ 0 11  0 11  0]
 [ 0 11  0 11  0]
 [ 0 11 11 11  0]
 [ 0 11  0 11  0]
 [ 0 11  0 11  0]
 [ 0 11  0 11  0]
 [ 0 11  0 11  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]]

[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 22 22  0  0]
 [ 0 22  0 22  0]
 [ 0 22  0 22  0]
 [ 0 22  0 22  0]
 [ 0 22 22  0  0]
 [ 0 22  0 22  0]
 [ 0 22  0 22  0]
 [ 0 22 22 22  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]]

[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 33  0  0]
 [ 0 33  0 33  0]
 [ 0 33  0  0  0]
 [ 0 33  0  0  0]
 [ 0 33  0  0  0]
 [ 0 33  0  0  0]
 [ 0 33  0 33  0]
 [ 0  0 33  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Which makes a lot more sense in my mind.

So it seems like my intuition for which way the axes should be visualized is reversed, and my array `a` should be of the shape (3,5,10). However, I have a whole project going around arrays of a certain format so I can't really change it at this point. I think of the order of the axes as arbitrary, and that's why I feel kind of restricted by this. So is there some quick or even built-in way I can get NumPy to print the axes in reverse, or arbitrary order? I checked out the documentation for `numpy.set_printoptions` and found nothing of the sort. I realize printing is kind of trivial, but I want to get around all the slicing I have to do to get a good look at my data. Or maybe someone can explain why it's not completely arbitrary and maybe I should think about array axes in a different way.

Comment: you should read up on (google) fortran vs. c ordered arrays. It'll give you a better understanding for how arrays work in memory, which will in turn help you understand how to wrangle with them. Numpy supports both ordering but defaults to c style ordering.

Comment: @Aaron unfortunately fortran versus c ordering refers to the layout in memory (consecutive rows or consecutive columns), but not the representation when printed.  `np.asfortranarray` will give you the same repr even if the internal memory layout is different.

Comment: @BradSolomon I was referring to the in-memory representation intentionally. It didn't answer the question directly, but I believe the knowledge useful nonetheless. Knowing more about the internal representation helped me greatly with understanding how to do more complex slicing and re-ordering of data to get the representation I wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately that is something you can't just do with a simple switch in NumPys print-options. You really have to reorder the axes to get the desired output (which is pretty easy).

If it's just for `print`ing, you can simply define a thin wrapper around the print function:

```
import numpy as np

def my_numpy_print(arr):
    if arr.ndim == 3:
        print(arr.transpose(2, 0, 1))
    else:  # no idea how you want it to be displayed for different dimensional arrays.
        print(arr)

arr = ...
my_numpy_print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0 11  0  0]
  [ 0 11  0 11  0]
  [ 0 11  0 11  0]
  [ 0 11 11 11  0]
  [ 0 11  0 11  0]
  [ 0 11  0 11  0]
  [ 0 11  0 11  0]
  [ 0 11  0 11  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0 22 22  0  0]
  [ 0 22  0 22  0]
  [ 0 22  0 22  0]
  [ 0 22  0 22  0]
  [ 0 22 22  0  0]
  [ 0 22  0 22  0]
  [ 0 22  0 22  0]
  [ 0 22 22 22  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0 33  0  0]
  [ 0 33  0 33  0]
  [ 0 33  0  0  0]
  [ 0 33  0  0  0]
  [ 0 33  0  0  0]
  [ 0 33  0  0  0]
  [ 0 33  0 33  0]
  [ 0  0 33  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB/Octave does display a matrix as you want.  The first axis varies fastest, last axis slowest.

`numpy` iterates over the axes in the other order.  Last axis varies fastest.

Making an array from consecutive numbers might help visualize the difference:

```
>> x = 1:24;
>> x=reshape(x,2,3,4)
x =
ans(:,:,1) =
   1   3   5
   2   4   6
ans(:,:,2) =
    7    9   11
    8   10   12
ans(:,:,3) =
   13   15   17
   14   16   18
ans(:,:,4) =
   19   21   23
   20   22   24

In [82]: x = np.arange(1,25).reshape(2,3,4)
In [83]: x
Out[83]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12]],

       [[13, 14, 15, 16],
        [17, 18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23, 24]]])
```

So in MATLAB the order is (rows, columns, planes), both for iteration and display.  `numpy` is (planes, rows, columns).

In `numpy`, there's another variable, the `order`:

```
In [85]: x = np.arange(1,25).reshape(2,3,4,order='F')
In [86]: x
Out[86]: 
array([[[ 1,  7, 13, 19],
        [ 3,  9, 15, 21],
        [ 5, 11, 17, 23]],

       [[ 2,  8, 14, 20],
        [ 4, 10, 16, 22],
        [ 6, 12, 18, 24]]])
```

But print still goes from left to right.

```
In [115]: for i in range(4): print(x[:,:,i])
[[1 3 5]
 [2 4 6]]
[[ 7  9 11]
 [ 8 10 12]]
[[13 15 17]
 [14 16 18]]
[[19 21 23]
 [20 22 24]]
```

---

Another way to visualize the ordering is to look at `strides`

```
In [119]: x = np.arange(1,25).reshape(2,3,4)
In [120]: x.strides
Out[120]: (48, 16, 4)
```

To step from one column to the next, it moves 4 bytes.  But from one plane to the next is a stride of 48 bytes (4 * 3 * 4).

In `order F`, the strides increment in the other order.

```
In [121]: np.arange(1,25).reshape(2,3,4,order='F').strides
Out[121]: (4, 8, 24)
```

---

I don't see anything in `np.set_printoptions` that gives us control over the axes ordering.  I don't where this printing is defined.